# Edit current cell via keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011, focus

In Excel for Macintosh 2011, when the cursor is in a particular cell of a spreadsheet and you wish for the focus to move to the edit line for that cell where the formula is displayed, is there a keyboard shortcut that exists or can be configured to move the focus other than by clicking with the mouse inside the formula editor?

This would be useful when the clipboard contains contents, a subset of which that you wish to become the cell's formula, once pasted, I would use other keyboard shortcuts to select portions of the formula and cut them for subsequent use in an adjacent cell.  For example, if the clipboard contains a string of latitude and longitude but I wish this split across two cells, one for latitude and one for longitude.

In short:

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Excel for Mac 2011 to edit the current cell? Similar to F2 in Excel for Windows

Comment: In Windows you have to disable the Advanced option "Allow Editing Directly In Cell", and then you hit F2 to start editing the current cell;  since you turned off direct editing within cell it jumps to the formula bar instead.  Perhaps look for similar in your OSX version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>***+<kbd>U</kbd> is what you want.

You don't need to change any other settings.